# What are these annotations in the JDK source code to verify parameters?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I looked at the JDK source code in IDEA, I found the following prompt.

[image: @NotNull(),@Nullable()]
[image: @Range(from=0,to=java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE)]

But I didn't find these annotations imported in the source code.

How can I get IDEA to add a hint like this to the source code I write?

Comment: See the documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/external-annotations.html and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/annotating-source-code.html .

Comment: Did you try clicking through them in your IDE to see the documentation?

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- Of course, but when I click, nothing happens, even when I click it while holding down the CTRL key.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thanks a lot. I think it must be `external-annotations`.

Comment: Odd; it works for me in Eclipse. Perhaps you don't have the JDK source code installed.

Answer (score 0):

Those are annotations for [JEE Bean Validation](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/bean-validation001.html). With a corresponding validator in place, a parameter can be validated against (possibly self-written) constraints before it is passed to the actual method. In case of a validation error, an accoring exception is thrown.

In your case, showed [external annotations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/external-annotations.html).